# ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero on a pandas dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a function that run over dataFrames and do some manipulations such as division, 
My issues is that some of the values are 0 and I get an error ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

my goal that if I have a 0 as denominator it return Nan 
my function look like this:

```
def get_roic(BS, KPI, IC):
     table = KPI.loc['fcf'].to_frame('fcf')
     table['Invested Capital'] = (BS.loc['st_debt'] + BS.loc['other_current_liabilities'] + 
     BS.loc['lt_debt'] + BS.loc['other_lt_liabilities'] + BS.loc['total_equity'])
     table['roic'] = table['fcf'].divide(table['Invested Capital'])
     table['revenue'] = IC.loc['revenue']
     table['fcf/revenue'] = table['fcf'].divide(table['revenue'])    
     return table
```

I tried many things such as:

```
def get_roic(BS, KPI, IC):
    table = KPI.loc['fcf'].to_frame('fcf')
    table['Invested Capital'] = (BS.loc['st_debt'] + BS.loc['other_current_liabilities'] + BS.loc['lt_debt'] + BS.loc['other_lt_liabilities'] + BS.loc['total_equity'])
    table['roic'] = table['fcf'].divide(table['Invested Capital'].where(table['Invested Capital'] != 0.0, np.nan))
    table['revenue'] = IC.loc['revenue']
    table['fcf/revenue'] = table['fcf'].divide(table['revenue'].where(table['revenue'] != 0.0, np.nan))     
    return table
```

But I do not get to make it work .. 
any ideas  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
df['fcf/revenue'] = df['fcf'].divide(df['revenue']) 
df['fcf/revenue'] = df['fcf/revenue'].replace(np.inf, np.nan)

   a   fcf  revenue  fcf/revenue
0  1  23.0     45.0     0.511111
1  2  34.0     56.0     0.607143
2  3  23.0      0.0          NaN
```

Comment: When I run:
df['fcf/revenue'] = df['fcf'].divide(df['revenue']) I get the error ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero and I run Pandas 1.0.1

Comment: Can you try setting those datatypes as np.float
`df['fcf'] = df['fcf'].astype(np.float)
df['revenue'] = df['revenue'].astype(np.float)`

And then try